# XSLT - get timezone offset from locale

Tags: java, xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon

Is it possible in XSLT to retrieve the time zone offset for a particular locale? There is a function named in-summer-time which takes in a dateTime and a locale identifier. It returns whether the given date falls under daylight savings or not for that country.

I have a requirement where I need to calculate the offset time for a particular locale. For example, I get the local time at Chile and I need to convert it to local time in UK. I can make use of the function in-summer-time to calculate for the daylight adjustments. But, where can I get the actual offset time for Chile?

P.S.: the function adjust-time-to-timezone does not help since it requires the offset time to be passed into the function(like 2013-05-10T08:10:30-05:00). I do not have the offset time (-05:00) information before hand.

Comment: You could load up a table of values which map from locale to offset. Start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Saxon extension function

saxon:adjust-to-civil-time

See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/adjust-to-civil-time

Which looks as if it might serve the purpose.

(The heading giving the function signature in the documentation is wrong.)

For example

saxon:adjust-to-civil-time(xs:dateTime('2013-12-06T12:00:00Z'), 'America/Santiago')

returns

2013-12-06T09:00:00-03:00

Comment: Thanks Mike. The adjust-to-civil-time function requires the input time in UTC format. In my case, the input time is the local time in Chile  which is the problem.

Comment: Yes, but it should be possible to use adjust-to-civil-time to get the information you need for the reverse conversion. If you take a UTC date/time and apply adjust-to-civil time, then getTimezone() on the result will give you the timezone displacement for Chile, and you can then apply this displacement using adjust-dateTime-to-timezone (perhaps after negating it?) to the local Chile time to convert it to UTC.